# daemonizing sidekiq with upstart script - is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sidekiq, upstart

I'm trying to daemonize sidekiq using two upstart scripts following [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart/manage-one) example.
Basically the workers service starts a fixed number of sidekiq services.

The problem is that the sidekiq script fails at the line of code where I am starting sidekiq. I've tried to run the command directly in bash and it works fine.

I tried all different commented lines and none works.

So my question is what am I doing wrong? Where can I see the error messages?

This is my modified sidekiq script:

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Sidekiq instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/sidekiq.conf then mange sidekiq with:
#   sudo start sidekiq index=0
#   sudo stop sidekiq index=0
#   sudo status sidekiq index=0
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service sidekiq {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

respawn
respawn limit 15 5

# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
stop on (stopping workers or runlevel [06])

# TERM and USR1 are sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq.  Without declaring these    as normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM USR1

instance $index

script
exec /bin/bash <<EOT
  # use syslog for logging
  # exec &> /dev/kmsg

  # pull in system rbenv
  # export HOME=/home/deploy
  # source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

  cd /home/rails
  touch /root/sidekick_has_started
  sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
  # exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
  # exec /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-3.1.3/bin/sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
  touch /root/sidekick_has_started_2
EOT
end script
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I have to load the RVM environment, I'm trying with 'source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global' but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, RVM env are required to be loaded in. Try this:

```
.....    
.....

script
exec /bin/bash <<EOT

  #export HOME=/home/deploy
  source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global

  cd /home/rails
  exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production

.....    
.....
```

Does it work?

Comment: I tried but I get the following error in the logs:
/bin/bash: line 10: exec: sidekiq: not found

Comment: It works I had to change the environment to source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p353 (without the @global part), thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sidekiq requires rvm environments. Below is the link to complete script and method on how to run sidekiq as usptart.
http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/sidekiq-upstart-job-or-sidekiq-as.html

Comment: @AjeetKhan as the upstart jobs are being replaced by systemd post Ubuntu 16. please update the article for New version with rvm as source.