# Booting up Sidekiq with Upstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, upstart

My goal is to have sidekiq start when the server boots up (I'm using EC2 with an auto-scaling group). I know there are a few other posts regarding getting sidekiq to start with upstart on boot, but I don't believe mine has been addressed specifically.

I'm using this wiki - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart/manage-many and have placed the scripts inside `/etc/init/sidekiq.conf` and `/etc/init/sidekiq-manager.conf`.

I've made a couple small modifications as directed in `/etc/init/sidekiq.conf`, changing:

- `# setuid apps`
  `# setgid apps` -> replaced `apps` with `ubuntu` in both lines, which is the deployment user.
- `export HOME=/home/apps` to `export HOME=/home/ubuntu`

I also have a `/etc/sidekiq.conf` that  includes the following line:

`/home/ubuntu/app_dir, 2`

Otherwise, these scripts are identical to those included in the referenced repo. I'm getting the following errors in my logs (`/var/log/upstart`)

`/bin/bash: line 19: cd: 2: No such file or directory
Could not locate Gemfile`

It appears as if it's attempting to change directory somewhere other than `/home/ubuntu/app_dir`, at which point it's in the wrong directory and cannot find my Gemfile.

Is there somewhere else I need to specify a correct path to my app directory?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are only using one app on the machine, don't use manage-many.  manage-one is simpler.

Comment: Thanks! That got me on the right track - at this point, my only issue seems to be loading the ruby env in this section of sidekiq.conf: `source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh`.  I've tried a solution similar to that suggested here in the accepted answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179503/daemonizing-sidekiq-with-upstart-script-is-not-working, but to no avail.  My error message is the following: `/bin/bash: line 9: exec: sidekiq: not found`

Comment: To be more specific, by "error message" I mean the output that I found in a sidekiq log file in `/var/log/upstart/`

Answer (score 1):

You can run `sidekiq` as an upstart job. Making a `sidekiq.conf` file in `/etc/init/` directory and put the upstart code to run sidekiq.
Here is the complete [**script**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/sidekiq-upstart-job-or-sidekiq-as.html) and the [**guide**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/sidekiq-upstart-job-or-sidekiq-as.html) to make sidekiq upstart job.

After making this job, sidekiq `start/stop/restart` would be easy with `sudo service` command.